# How do I subscribe to an RSS FeedBurner feed using Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, rss, internet-explorer-11

I can't seem to find a way to subscribe to rss feeds provided by FeedBurner using IE11.  Typically a site will have a general "subscribe to feed" link, which IE will recognize, however FeedBurner appears to restrict subscriptions to a limited number of readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/795260/ie11-broken-rss-feeds) filled against this issue. We have to wait for Microsoft to fix it.

EDIT:
After applying the latest updates released on 10th December I can access FeedBurner feeds without any problems, the issue is fixed.